# Google Cloud Pub Sub still sending notifications even after stopping all events for the user

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-cloud-pubsub

In my node server, I am taking user's gmail inbox permissions and adding a watcher to all of them using google cloud's pub sub.

Here's the code:

```
async addWatcherToGmailInbox({
    gmailInboxRefreshToken,
  }: {
    gmailInboxRefreshToken: string;
  }): Promise<boolean> {
    const auth = await this.loadAuth(gmailInboxRefreshToken);
    const gmail = google.gmail({
      version: 'v1',
      auth,
    });
    await gmail.users.watch({
      userId: 'me',
      requestBody: {
        labelIds: ['INBOX'],
        topicName: 'projects/<project-name>/topics/<topic-name>',
      },
    });
    return true;
  }
```

But when user unlinks his gmail account from my platform, I stop the notifications first and then revoke the token. But somehow, I still get notifications in my pub sub subscriber `on` event.

Stopping notifications code:

```
async removeWatcherFromGmailInbox({
    gmailInboxRefreshToken,
  }: {
    gmailInboxRefreshToken: string;
  }): Promise<boolean> {
    const auth = await this.loadAuth(gmailInboxRefreshToken);
    const gmail = google.gmail({
      version: 'v1',
      auth,
    });
    gmail.users.stop({
      userId: 'me',
    });
    return true;
  }
```

My pub sub subscriber event where I'm getting notifications:

```
const pubsub = new PubSub({
      projectId: <project-name>,
    });

    this.logger.log('Google Pubsub initialized, fetching topics...');

    const subs = await pubsub.getSubscriptions();
    const sub = subs[0][0];

    // Receive callbacks for new messages on the subscription
    sub.on('message', (message) => {
      this.logger.log('Received message:', message.data.toString());

      const data = JSON.parse(message.data.toString());
    });

    // Receive callbacks for errors on the subscription
    sub.on('error', (error) => {
      this.logger.error('Received error:', error);
    });
```

What am I missing to stop notifications for a user when he/she wants to revoke the token.

Note: I did log the response of stop function. It returns empty body just like it's mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop to publish message in topic, but there is still messages in the subscription and PubSub try to deliver them until ack or message expiration. You can also [purge](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview) the subscription